# \pbox vertical alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes

What's going on here, why are the `TEXT`s not aligned?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Short}
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Long Text}
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Short}
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Long Text}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: Clearly pbox is not adjusting for the depth of `g`. Why not use a standard `\parbox` ?

Comment: The contents of each `\pbox` is pushed at the bottom, as requested by the final `[b]` argument. All boxes have the same total height, so this is what you get. Do you want `\pbox[c][20pt][t]` instead?

Comment: Of course, the `g`, I should have seen that. @David: I use `\pbox` inside tikz to position a vertical line centered below the boxs. I don't know the widths.

Comment: yes saw that now, I generated an example but egreg and Harish beat me to it, but I'd probably just use a simple 1 column tabular for that. For more general variable sized parbox varwidth package is probably more robust.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`g` in `Long` has a depth where as in `Short` no letter has depth. This is why the misalignment comes. To correct it, you may add a `\vphantom{g}` to `Short` or `\smash` the `Long` (or only `g`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ \vphantom{g}Short}%
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Long Text}%
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ \vphantom{g}Short}%
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Long Text}%
\hrule
%
\bigskip
%
\hrule
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Short}%
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ \smash{Long} Text}%
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Short}%
\pbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ \smash{Long} Text}%
\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disregard automatically the depth of the last line, you can use the `varwidth` package and a custom made command based on it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand{\spbox}{} % check whether it's already defined    
\def\spbox#1#{\def\spboxtemp{#1}\spboxaux}% absorb the possible optional arguments
\newcommand\spboxaux[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\varwidth\spboxtemp{#1}#2\par\kern-\prevdepth\endvarwidth
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\spbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Short}
\spbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Long Text}
\spbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Short}
\spbox[c][20pt][b]{\textwidth}{TEXT\\ Long Text}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image]